# piston-django how many methods should a single handler contain

Tags: python, django, django-piston

I've been building a handler class for each method I want to map to the url file. Is my approach correct or wrong? because I don't seem to find a way to map a resource to a method they all map to an entire class.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentations seems very clear https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!resources

```
from piston.handler import BaseHandler
from myapp.models import Blogpost

class BlogpostHandler(BaseHandler):
   allowed_methods = ('GET',)
   model = Blogpost   

   def read(self, request, post_slug):
      ...
```

> Piston lets you map resource to
>   models, and by doing so, it will do a
>   lot of the heavy lifting for you.
>
> A resource can be just a class, but
>   usually you would want to define at
>   least 1 of 4 methods:
>
> `read` is called on GET requests, and
>   should never modify data (idempotent.)
>
> `create` is called on POST, and creates
>   new objects, and should return them
>   (or `rc.CREATED`.)
>
> `update` is called on PUT, and should
>   update an existing product and return
>   them (or `rc.ALL_OK`.)
>
> `delete` is called on DELETE, and should
>   delete an existing object. Should not
>   return anything, just `rc.DELETED`.

Also https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!mapping-urls

In urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from piston.resource import Resource
from mysite.myapp.api.handlers import BlogpostHandler

blogpost_handler = Resource(BlogpostHandler)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^blogpost/(?P<post_slug>[^/]+)/', blogpost_handler),
   url(r'^blogposts/', blogpost_handler),
)
```